# How to move an element into the next parent element in the DOM?

Tags: jquery, dom, insertafter

I'm struggling to move an element into the next element in the DOM. I can move it but it keeps repeating itself into the other div's with the same class.

This is my HTML:

```
    <p>The first text that needs to be moved</p>
    <div class="tmb">
      <span class="price">500</span>
    </div>
    <p>Second text that needs to be moved</p>
    <div class="tmb">
      <span class="price">500</span>
    </div>
```

What I want to happen is that the first `p` element will be inserted after the first `.price` element. The second `p` element will be inserted after the second `.price` element. I can't give the `p` elements a class because they are created dynamically.

I have this jQuery:

```
   $(".tmb").prev("p").insertAfter("span.price");
```

But this moves the `p` element after every `.price` element, which is logically. I just want it to move after the first `.price` element that it comes across in the DOM.

Comment: Just as an addendum the vanilla JS way: `document.querySelectorAll(".tmb").forEach(t => t.append(t.previousElementSibling))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you could loop through all `p` elements as there are multiple, and then use `appendTo()` to add them to their related `.tmb`. Try this:

```js
$('p').each((i, p) => $(p).appendTo($(p).next('.tmb')));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>The first text that needs to be moved</p>
<div class="tmb">
  <span class="price">500</span>
</div>
<p>Second text that needs to be moved</p>
<div class="tmb">
  <span class="price">500</span>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could loop through all the `.tmb` elements which are preceded by a `p` and `insertAfter()` the `.price` contained there.

```js
$('p + .tmb').each((i, t) => $(t).prev('p').insertAfter($(t).find('.price')));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>The first text that needs to be moved</p>
<div class="tmb">
  <span class="price">500</span>
</div>
<p>Second text that needs to be moved</p>
<div class="tmb">
  <span class="price">500</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This works perfect, and is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: As there's no other element in `.tmb` other than `.price` you could just do `$(t).prev(".p").appendTo(t)` instead of the `.insertAfter(...)` + `.find()`